# How to set position directly to the indoor street view

Tags: google-street-view

I want to set directly on the street view of the indoor view.
For the example, I want to set following URL.
https://www.google.com/maps/@35.0634109,135.8086139,3a,75y,180.01h,89t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1swNnGs1ttR8WivRd3l250PA!2e0!3e2

And I tried the code like following, but it had been set to the position of another.

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(35.0634109,135.8086139));
```

Can I set the position to indoor view directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a panoramaOptions variable containing the details about position, and then use it when instantiating the panorama. 
This example might help you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have changed the LatLng to (35.0634109,135.8086139) in the sample above, but it did not work.
Do I need to be set to something other than LatLng?